# How to add a middle legend in the slider on Shiny R?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a shiny slider that goes from 1 to 100. I need a label in the middle showing the best "position" in this slider. Like this:

[image]

Does anyone can help me?

Comment: Could you add sample code you have done so far?

Comment: I think the only way is add an actionbutton, after you click the button, update the slide input to your 'best position'

Comment: This is the code of the slider so far: 

sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 
                    value=c(50), 
                    ticks=TRUE
                   
                    
                    )

Comment: @FernandaAvelar, could you please edit your code with [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of writing a one line code in your comments?